# Longitude Latitude of Android device

Tags: android, android-mapview, latitude-longitude

When the longitude latitude value change in a mobile device?. If I took the device to some other place it changes I knew that. But I need to know while I tilt the device, whether the value changes or not?

Then help to draw a polygon on mapview with related to the change of angle of device(I know the length of line and angle of change). Otherwise if I can find the value(log,lat) of mapview then help to do that by default my first is (0,5).

Comment: It keeps changes all the time, evenif you are at same place for whole day, it keeps changing in small small values.

Comment: @Kedarnath really.... i dont know!!!!

Comment: @SimplePlan, MD, that's because I have more exp in GPS than you :)

Comment: @Kedarnath That's very good. Can i ask little bit help?

Comment: Sure, Please, ask it. I like to share knowledge

Comment: There's no relationship whatsoever between GPS and Accelerometer unless you set one. GPS doesn't care about the angle of your device and GPS data are not so stable not to change at all even when the device is not moving.

Comment: I'm gonna use network provider instead of Gps to get log,lat value and for angle using Accelerometer. I need the value of log,lat for small change of yaw,pitch and roll. Possible?

Comment: @user3647272 No, the GPS sensor of a mobile device isn't accurate enough for this.

Comment: K then how should I make this. Can u suggest any solution for this problem. Can anyone give some tips to draw polygon on mapview depending on the angle variation. I know the distance of lines but don't know the long,latt value to place that lines.